# long delay between serverside JSON and jqGrid loadComplete on asp.net mvc site

Tags: asp.net-mvc, json, jqgrid

i have an asp.net mvc site where i load a jqgrid with json data

Here is my controller action code:

```
    public ActionResult GridData(GridData args)
    {
        IEnumerable<Application> applications = EntityModel.GetAll().ToList();
        applications = FilterEntities(applications);
        if (args.sidx.IsNullOrEmpty() || args.sidx == "Id")
        {
            args.sidx = "Name";
            args.sord = "asc";
        }
        applications = applications.GridSort(args.sidx, args.sord);
        var paginatedData = applications.GridPaginate(args.page ?? 1, args.rows ?? 10,
                                                      i => new
                                                      {
                                                          i.Id,
                                                          Name = "<div class='showDescription' Id= '" + i.MyId + "'>" + i.Name + "</div>",
                                                          MyId = string.Format("<a                                                               i.LastUpdated,
                                                          i.LastUpdatedColumn
                                                      });

        return Json(paginatedData);
    }
```

and here is my javascript code:

```
function doInitCrudGrid(controller, names, model, editable, querystring) {
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid({
    mtype: 'POST',
    url: "/" + controller + "/GridData?" + querystring,
    datatype: "json",
    colNames: names,
    colModel: model,
    imgpath: "/Scripts/jqGrid/themes/steel/images",
    rowNum: 20,
    rowList: [10, 20, 50, 999],
    altRows: true,
    altclass: "altRow",
    jsonReader: {
        root: "Rows",
        page: "Page",
        total: "Total",
        records: "Records",
        repeatitems: false,
        id: "Id"
    },
    pager: "#pager",
    height: "auto",
    sortname: "Id",
    viewrecords: true,
    sortorder: "desc",
    loadComplete: function() {

        alert("Load Complete");
    },
    ondblClickRow: function(rowid) { }
});
```

i have a breakpoint on the

```
return Json(paginatedData);
```

line and that gets hit very quick but after that it takes about 10 seconds for the:

```
 alert("Load Complete");
```

and for the rendering to show up on the web page.

Is there anyway to debug this or way to see why there would be this large delay between finishing the server side json and histting the loadcomplete on the javascript callback ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To be sure where you have a problem, I would recommend you to measure the time on the both sides. For example in your JavaScript do following:

```
var startTime = new Date();
// do something
var totalTime = new Date() - startTime;
```

and inside your controller action

```
using System;

public ActionResult GridData(GridData args) {
    DateTime startTime = DateTime.Now;
    // do something
    TimeSpan totalTime = DateTime.Now - startTime;
    // save or log totalTime
    System.DateTime date4 = date3.Subtract(diff1);
    return Json(paginatedData);
}
```

After this you will exactly know on which side you have your main performance problems.

Comment: if you read my question above the time on the server controller action is very quick.  I can tell this just from putting in breakpoints.  The delay is AFTER the "return Json()" is called so measuring the time before is not necessary

Comment: And what about measuring of executing time of the different peaces of your javascript code? You can use `$("#grid").getGridParam("totaltime")` inside of `loadComplete` event to see the time of building jqGrid from the JSON input.

Answer (score 0):

How much data are you returning?  It could be taking a long time to serialise and deserialise.  Have you considered returning a PartialView instead and replacing the contents of a div with the returned html?

Comment: i am returning about 20 rows at once and about 10 columns so i wouldn't have thought it would take that long.  Why would the partial view be any faster?

Comment: I was only thinking that if you were returning a large amount of data that it might be faster as there would be no serialisation.  But 200 cells of data is not a lot really though i can't help but think serialisation might be playing a part.  Have you tried returning a single row and timing htat?

Comment: good idea.  i will play around with the json "content" and see if its a function of size of fields, etc

Comment: @ooo, how did you go playing around with the content?  Any new information, or even a solution?