# jqGrid, datatype: function() and access to sord, sidx, etc

Tags: asp.net, jquery, jqgrid

I'm attempting to implement the jqGrid using a WebMethod on the page that hosts the grid. This works if I using the dataType: function() in the jqGrid:

```
 $("#mygrid").jqGrid({
     ...
     datatype: function() {
          $.ajax({
              url: "myPage.aspx/gridData",
              type: "POST",
              contentType: "application/json; char=utf-8"
              ...
          });
     }
  )};
```

In my code behind of the same page, I have my method:

```
[WebMethod()]
public static List<MyData> gridData() {
    return MyClass.getData();
}
```

The only thing I'm not sure of is how I can get access to the data used for paging, sorting (sord, sidx, etc.)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you to use standard `datatype: 'json'` instead of `datatype` as function. You need only use additionally

```
datatype: 'json',
ajaxGridOptions: { contentType: 'application/json; charset=utf-8' },
mtype: 'GET',
```

(see [Setting the content-type of requests performed by jQuery jqGrid](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731) for example)

and return jqGridTable class instance defined like following

```
public class jqGridTable
{
    public int total { get; set; }      // total number of pages
    public int page { get; set; }       // current zero based page number
    public int records { get; set; }    // total number of records
    public List<jqGridRow> rows { get; set; }
}
public class jqGridRow
{
    public string id { get; set; }
    public List<string> cell { get; set; }
}
```

Or if we want use the most compact form of data transferred from server to client then following

```
// jsonReader: { repeatitems : true, cell:"", id: "0" }
public class jqGridTable {
    public int total { get; set; }          // total number of pages
    public int page { get; set; }           // current zero based page number
    public int records { get; set; }        // total number of records
    public List<List<string>> rows { get; set; }// first element of row must be id
}
```

Probably you should use a little other `jsonReader` to be able to decode data from the `d` property of the web service results (see [Jqgrid 3.7 does not show rows in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054463/jqgrid-3-7-does-not-show-rows-in-internet-explorer/3061669#3061669)).

To support server side paging and sorting you should add

```
int page, int rows, string sidx, string sord
```

to the list of parameters of your service.

**UPDATED**: Other link [jqgrid Page 1 of x pager](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3161302/jqgrid-page-1-of-x-pager/3161542#3161542) has practically full code of both jqGrid and the ASMX service. You can use the following simple `jsonReader`:

```
jsonReader: { root: "d.rows", page: "d.page", total: "d.total",
              records: "d.records", id: "d.names" }
```

Comment: I actually came across your example earlier. The first part is missing the "ts" definition so it won't work and I'm not sure what it is. Any tips?

Also, if I'm not mistaken, I cannot use "get" with json because of security. A webservice will only respond back in json if a post occurs.

Comment: Probably you mean `ts` from http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731. It is only a code fragment from the source code of jqGrid. You can download the full source code from http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=6. You do can use HTTP GET with JSON. About security you probably mean JSON inject. It is a subject of separate discussion. In my main project where I use jqGrid for example I use HTTP GET and have secure solution. One should goes in details to explain this.

Comment: Thanks for the tips Oleg. I'm well on my way to having a working solution.

Comment: You welcome! If you will have other problem you can ask me more. At least you should have one working solution. If you will have problem I could post an url with a working Visual Studio project using jqGrid and an asmx web service.