# jqGrid rowid naming conflict during save

Tags: jqgrid

I need some help with jqGrid. I have a table with the primary key column named 'id'. It seems that there is naming conflict with jqGrid when the inline edit does ajax post back to save data. The *rowid* used as the unique identifier is also named 'id' in jqGrid.

Is it possible to change the default rowid variable name to something else, such as '_id' to avoid naming conflict?  Did I miss something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different ways to solve your problem.

You can not change the id name used in jqGrid, but you can rename any parameters of ajax requests. For example you can use `prmNames: {id:"_id"}` option of jqGrid.

If you have a column in the table which has primary key and which can be used to identify a grid row, you can set `key: true` in the column definition. As a result the column with `key: true` will be used by jqGrid instead of additional `id`. Moreover this option can be used also to reduce the size of data (see [Jqgrid 3.7 does not show rows in internet explorer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054463/jqgrid-3-7-does-not-show-rows-in-internet-explorer) as an example).

Comment: I think the first suggestion with prmNames should resolve my issue. The second suggestion is probably the more proper way to resolve the ambiguous naming issue. I will look into it too. Thank you!