# jqGrid colModel and jsonReader with no cell

Tags: jquery, json, jqgrid

The following json and jqgrid options give me no data in my grid.

```
var grid = jQuery("#grid")[0];
grid.addJSONData({ // the json
    total: 1,
    page: 1,
    records: 10,
    items: [
        { ProductID: '1', Name: 'Coke' },
        { ProductID: '2', Name: 'Pepsi' },
        { ProductID: '3', Name: 'L&P' },
        { ProductID: '4', Name: 'A&B' },
        { ProductID: '5', Name: 'All Star' },
        { ProductID: '6', Name: 'Wai' },
        { ProductID: '7', Name: 'cd' },
        { ProductID: '8', Name: 'LV' },
        { ProductID: '9', Name: 'DD' },
        { ProductID: '10', Name: 'aW' }
    ]
});

// jqGrid options
{
    ...
    colNames: ['ProductID', 'Name'],
    colModel: [{ name: 'ProductID', Label: 'Id' },
               { name: 'Name', Label: 'Name'}],
    jsonReader: {
        root: 'items',
        cell: ''
    },
   ...
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your data has no `id` properties. It seems that `ProductID` play the role of id of your data. So you should use additional `key:true` option in the definition of the `ProductID` column or include 'id:ProductID' in the `jsonReader`.

Moreover the `Label` property should be written in low case: `label`. It replace the value from the column header `colNames`. If you use `label` property for all columns you not need more define `colNames` array.

If you want to fill the jqGrid with the local data the most effective way is to use [addRowData](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki%3aretrieving_data#array_data) function. In the case you should use `localReader` instead of `jsonReader`. It can be used to add not only a row, but an array of row data. In the case of arrays as data the first parameter should be the name of id property. So your code could look like following:

```
var myData = [
        { ProductID: '1', Name: 'Coke' },
        { ProductID: '2', Name: 'Pepsi' },
        { ProductID: '3', Name: 'L&P' },
        { ProductID: '4', Name: 'A&B' },
        { ProductID: '5', Name: 'All Star' },
        { ProductID: '6', Name: 'Wai' },
        { ProductID: '7', Name: 'cd' },
        { ProductID: '8', Name: 'LV' },
        { ProductID: '9', Name: 'DD' },
        { ProductID: '10', Name: 'aW' }
    ];
jQuery("#grid").jqGrid ('addRowData', 'ProductID', myData);
```

If all this will not help, you should include in your question the whole code which can be used to reproduce your problem.

Comment: The data is not really local.  I just made a local object to troubleshoot.

Comment: @Travis Heseman: We should divide quick fixing of your problem from optimization. You have to define `key:true` or `id:ProductID` in the `jsonReader` **to make your grid working**. I wrote only that it will be not the optimal code. In one of my first posts on the stackoverflow (see http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2660226/should-one-replace-the-usage-addjsondata-of-jqgrid-to-the-usage-of-setgridparam and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2675625/setting-the-content-type-of-requests-performed-by-jquery-jqgrid/2678731#2678731) I explain that jqGrid has better ways to load JSON data.

Comment: @Travis Heseman: If you post more code of your program I could show you how to say `jqGrid` to load the JSON data for you instead of loading the data per `addJSONData`. The http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054463/jqgrid-3-7-does-not-show-rows-in-internet-explorer could be also interesting for you.

Comment: Actually just got it working with your suggestion of key:true.