# JqGrid not loading data from asp.net mvc action

Tags: asp.net-mvc, jqgrid

I run into this problem few hours ago, and I can't get around it.

I'm trying to implement JqGrid into my ASP.NET MVC application. I was using examples from Phil Haack's [blog post](http://haacked.com/archive/2009/04/14/using-jquery-grid-with-asp.net-mvc.aspx).

I imported js and css:

```
    <link href="/Content/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <link href="/Content/ui.jgrid.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css"  />
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-1.4.1.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js"></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/jquery.jqGrid.min.js" ></script>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="/Scripts/grid.local-en.js" ></script>
```

I put this code in view:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    jQuery(document).ready(function() {
        jQuery("#list").jqGrid({
            url: '/Ticket/All/',
            datatype: 'json',
            mtype: 'GET',
            colNames: ['Id', 'Hardware', 'Issue', 'IssueDetails', 'RequestedBy', 'AssignedTo', 'Priority', 'State'],
            colModel: [
          { name: 'Id', index: 'Id', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Hardware', index: 'Hardware', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Issue', index: 'Issue', width: 200, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'IssueDetails', index: 'IssueDetails', width: 200, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'RequestedBy', index: 'RequestedBy', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'AssignedTo', index: 'AssignedTo', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'Priority', index: 'Priority', width: 40, align: 'left' },
          { name: 'State', index: 'State', width: 40, align: 'left'}],
            pager: jQuery('#pager'),
            rowNum: 10,
            rowList: [5, 10, 20, 50],
            sortname: 'Id',
            sortorder: "desc",
            viewrecords: true,
            caption: 'My first grid'
        });
    }); 
</script>

<h2>My Grid Data</h2>
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

And here is my test action in Ticket controller:

```
 public ActionResult All(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
    {
        var jsonData = new
        {
            total = 1, // we'll implement later 
            page = page,
            records = 3, // implement later 
            rows = new[]{
                new {id = 1, cell = new[] {"1", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}},
                new {id = 2, cell = new[] {"2", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}},
                new {id = 3, cell = new[] {"3", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}}
            }
        };
        return Json(jsonData);
    }
```

At this moment, I can see empty grid, but whole page is covered with with overlay, and I can't click anything (that's probably "loading" overlay).

What's wrong in here?

Comment: Use FireBug (for example) and see if there're JavaScript errors or how your AJAX requests look like, if there're errors, and if your All action hit at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

kMike,

you need to add the following to the return statement (assuming mvc 2):

```
return Json(jsonData, JsonRequestBehavior.AllowGet);
```

that should hopefully fix the problem. also, as noted in the comment on the OT, check in firebug for any issues with the request.

[edit] - also make you signature along these lines for tighter coupling to the return type:

```
public JsonResult All(string sidx, string sord, int page, int rows)
```

plus, had this in my bookmarks: http://techshorts.blogspot.com/2009/04/json-for-jqgrid-from-aspnet-mvc.html

enjoy :)

Comment: Thanks Jim, that moved me few steps further. :)

Answer (score 2):

I seen some more errors, so I decide to write you additionally.

First, the most important thing is you should change the order of JavaScript files. The file `grid.local-en.js` must be included **before** `jquery.jqGrid.min.js`.

I recommend you to use [jquery-1.4.3.js](http://docs.jquery.com/Downloading_jQuery#Download_jQuery) which works **more quickly** with CSS used intensively by jqGrid. Including of `jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.min.js` is not required for jqGrid. jqGrid use only jQuery UI CSS file (like `jquery-ui-1.8.5.custom.css`). Only if you use functionality described in [jQuery UI Integrations](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:jquery_ui_methods) then you will need it.

Now some small optimization remarks:

The value `align: 'left'` is default, so you don't need include it. The `pager: jQuery('#pager')` can be reduced to `pager: '#pager'` and

```
<table id="list" class="scroll" cellpadding="0" cellspacing="0"></table>
<div id="pager" class="scroll" style="text-align:center;"></div>
```

to the

```
<table id="list"></table>
<div id="pager"></div>
```

because jqGrid since many last versions makes all changes needed in the `<table>` and the pager `<div>` [itself](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:first_grid#explanation_of_code).

If your grid has a column which is **unique** and can be id of the grid row you can include `key:true` in the corresponding column definition, like in your case:

```
{ name: 'Id', index: 'Id', key: true , width: 40 }
```

It will allow you to reduce a little the size of data send from the server. You can add the parameter `jsonReader: { cell:"" }` and change the part of your code of `All` method, which generate `rows` to

```
rows = new[]{
    new[] {"1", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}},
    new[] {"2", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}},
    new[] {"3", "hard asdf", "issue adfds", "more issue", "someuser", "otheruser", "2", "Submitted"}}
}
```

(see [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3054463/jqgrid-3-7-does-not-show-rows-in-internet-explorer/3061669#3061669) or read in the [documentation](http://www.trirand.com/jqgridwiki/doku.php?id=wiki:retrieving_data#json_data) more about this.)

Comment: Hi Oleg. Thanks for few additional hints. I already come to problem with loading locale after jqGrid and fixed it. 
I use jquery-ui for datepickar, that's why it's included.
Thanks also for other useful hints.

Comment: I still have some issues, though. Now grid is more or less working, the way i want to, but there is still grey overlay that hides rest of the page, and makes all the elements "unclickable". I presume, that's some problem with css.

Comment: @kMike: Do you use <!DOCTYPE html ...> declaration as the first line of your HTML? You can examine the overlay with Developer Tools of IE8, Chrome or with Firebug. Which id has the gray overlay?

Comment: yes I use DOCTYE. The lui_list is the id of div that covers whole page. From what I understand, that's responsible for blocking page, while loading data, but It stays on, after loading of data.