# Losing edited cell data after paging

Tags: jqgrid, pagination

I'm building a completely "client side" grid however if I enable inline editing, the changes I make are lost if I change the grid page.

Hopefully someone can point out what I'm missing

The Grid setup is shown below along with the function I call to fill it with test data:

```
var myGrid;
var lastgridsel;
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    myGrid = jQuery("#mygrid").jqGrid({
        datatype: 'local',
        colModel: [
            { name: 'AID', label: 'AID', index: 'AID', width: 100, editable: false,
              sorttype: "int" },
            { name: 'MS', label: 'MS', index: 'MS', width: 300, editable: false },
            { name: 'GROUP', label: 'GROUP', index: 'GROUP', width: 100,
              editable: false },
            { name: 'REV', label: 'REV', index: 'REV', width: 100,
              editable: false },
            { name: 'OPT', label: 'OPT', index: 'OPT', width: 100, editable: true,
              edittype: 'text' }
        ],
        pager: '#mypager',
        rowNum: 10,
        rowList: [10, 20, 500],
        viewrecords: true,
        loadonce: true,
        autowidth: true,
        sortname: 'AID',
        sortorder: 'desc',
        cellsubmit: 'clientArray',
        onSelectRow: function(id) {
            if (id && id !== lastgridsel) {
                jQuery('#mygrid').saveRow(lastgridsel, false, 'clientArray');
                jQuery('#mygrid').editRow(id, true);
                lastgridsel = id;
            }
        }
    });
});

var mydata = [];
function InitNew() {
    for (var i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        mydata.push({ AID: i, MS: "123", GROUP: "456", REV: "78", OPT: "8" });
    }
    myGrid.setGridParam({ data: mydata }).trigger("reloadGrid");
}
```

This shows 10 pages, 100 records. If I click the "OPT" column, I can change the value in the textbox and when I click another row, the data appears to be saved. However, once I go to another page and back to the first page, the data reverts to its original value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Oleg - thanks a million. Your answer works really well. I posted the question on the official jqgrid support forum and there is another workaround which could help. Thread is at http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/help/losing-edited-cell-data-after-paging/#p18567.

Summary: If building the grid using pure clientside code, you need to replace

```
myGrid.setGridParam({ data: mydata }).trigger("reloadGrid");
```

with

```
myGrid.setGridParam({ data: mydata });
myGrid[0].refreshIndex();
myGrid.trigger("reloadGrid");
```

Comment: I should also mention it requires a line in the options:

localReader : {id:'AID'},

Comment: It's very good that now we have a working solution! I wrote just now  the suggestion the include description of `refreshIndex` method in the documentation of jqGrid (see http://www.trirand.com/blog/?page_id=393/bugs/data-parameter-are-not-modified-during-inline-editing/#p18613).

Answer (score 2):

I am not sure whether it is a bug in the version of 3.7.x or not, but currently if you save local data with respect of inline editing (`saveRow` or `editRow` methods) the internal data parameter of jqGrid will be **not modified**.

To fix the problem you can define function like

```
var myAfterSave = function(rowid, response) {  // aftersavefunc
    var index = parseInt(rowid, 10);
    var d = myGrid.getGridParam("data");
    var rowdata = myGrid.getRowData(rowid);
    d[rowdata.AID].OPT = rowdata.OPT;
};
```

and modify the lines

```
jQuery('#mygrid').saveRow(lastgridsel, false, 'clientArray');
jQuery('#mygrid').editRow(id, true);
```

to the lines

```
jQuery('#mygrid').saveRow(lastgridsel, false, 'clientArray', null, myAfterSave);
jQuery('#mygrid').editRow(id, true, null, null, 'clientArray', null, myAfterSave);
```